# is it possible to use cobbler using windows dhcp server or without dhcp?

Tags: windows, redhat, dhcp, dhcp-server, cobbler

I want to configure cobbler in my network but my network already managing by a windows 2k8r2 dhcp server. Is it any way to configure without dhcp server ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, managing a DHCP server is completely optional for Cobbler.

Just set

```
manage_dhcp: 0
```

in your `/etc/cobbler/settings` file.